# How to combine all similar array looping methods? Java 1.8

Tags: java

In order to study programming, I am making a game 2048 in java. The game has a class in which there are many repetitive fragments - field iteration loops. The question is, is it possible to create such a method that will accept the values of the enumeration bounds and the executable code?

Something like this both for assignment and comparison.

```java
public void forField(int borderX, int borderY, ??? code){
    for (int x = 0; x < borderX; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < borderY; y++)
            do code;
}

public boolean checkField(int borderX, int borderY, ??? code, boolean default_answer){
    for (int x = 0; x < borderX; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < borderY; y++)
            return code;
    return default_answer;
}
```

If not, can you recommend how to make my code better? Thank you for your attention.

```java
public class Field {
    private int[][] field;
    private int width, heigth;

    public Field(int sizeX, int sizeY) {
        this.width = sizeX;
        this.heigth = sizeY;
        this.field = new int[sizeX][sizeY];
    }

    public int getCell(int x, int y) {
        return this.field[x][y];
    }

    public void setCell(int val, int x, int y) {
        this.field[x][y] = val;
    }

    // for restart
    public void reset() {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < heigth; y++)
                this.field[x][y] = 0;
    }

    // for step cancelling function
    public void copyOf(Field f) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < heigth; y++)
                this.field[x][y] = f.getCell(x, y);
    }

    // can field changed after pressing a key
    public boolean isEqualTo(Field f) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < heigth; y++)
                if (field[x][y] != f.getCell(x, y))
                    return false;
        return true;
    }

    private boolean canMergeByY() {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < heigth - 1; y++)
                if (field[x][y] == field[x][y + 1])
                    return true;
        return false;
    }

    private boolean canMergeByX() {
        for (int x = 0; x < width - 1; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < heigth; y++)
                if (field[x][y] == field[x + 1][y])
                    return true;
        return false;
    }

    // checking the possibility of continuing the game
    public boolean canMerge() {
        return canMergeByX() && canMergeByY();
    }

    // checking 0 and 2048 cells for different tasks
    public boolean contains(int i) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < heigth; y++)
                if (field[x][y] == i)
                    return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `???` in `forField` can just be a `BiConsumer<Integer, Integer>`, or you can declare your own `IntBiConsumer` interface if you don't like boxing:

```
interface IntBiConsumer {
    void accept(int i, int j);
}
```

`forField` can then be declared as:

```
public void forField(int borderX, int borderY, IntBiConsumer code){
    for (int x = 0; x < borderX; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < borderY; y++)
           code.accept(x, y);
}
```

`copyOf` can then be written as:

```
public void copyOf(Field f) {
    forField(width, height, (x, y) -> {
        this.field[x][y] = f.getCell(x, y);
    });
}
```

---

`checkField` is a little bit more tricky, your proposed code wouldn't actually work, because you are not checking anything before you `return` in the inner loop. The loops will only loop once, and return immediately. It should be more like:

```
public boolean checkField(int borderX, int borderY, ??? condition, boolean default_answer){
    for (int x = 0; x < borderX; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < borderY; y++)
            if (condition) 
                return !default_answer;
    return default_answer;
}
```

`???` here can be a `BiPredicate<Integer, Integer>`, or your own interface like this:

```
interface IntBiPredicate {
    boolean test(int i, int j);
}
```

`checkField` can then be declared like this:

```
public boolean checkField(int borderX, int borderY, IntBiPredicate condition, boolean defaultAnswer){
    for (int x = 0; x < borderX; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < borderY; y++)
            if (condition.test()) 
                return !defaultAnswer;
    return defaultAnswer;
}
```

`isEqualTo` can be rewritten as:

```
public boolean isEqualTo(Field f) {
    return checkField(width, height, (x, y) -> field[x][y] != f.getCell(x, y), true);
}
```